# How to check if path is behind a symlink

Tags: bash

I have a list of files and I need to know which of those files are behind symlinks.
eg.

```
var/storage/media/foo.jpg
var/storage/documents/bar.doc
var/logs/baz.log
```

if only `var/storage` is a symlink, then I want to get the list:

```
var/storage/media/foo.jpg
var/storage/documents/bar.doc
```

Each file in the original list may or may not exist
(eg. even if `symlinked/documents` folder is missing, I still want `bar.doc` to be in results.

How can I achieve this in bash?
If possible oneliner would be best.

Comment: In what form is the list provided? Is it a text file (i.e. newline-terminated lines)?

Comment: Its output from a command with one path per line.
To be exact output of `git status -s | grep -E '^ +D' | sed -E 's/^ +D +//'`.

Answer (score 1):

Find a way to convert a given path into a list of its parents. (In Bash it's easier by stripping away the last component, in other languages it might be easier to split the path into components and re-join them in a loop – assuming it's a Unix-style path with no drive letters or other fancy syntax).

Then, for each item in the resulting list, do the usual check for whether it's a symlink (e.g. in sh/bash do `[ -h the_path ]` for each parent/grandparent/etc).

Oneliner:

```bash
cat files.txt | perl -MList::Util=reductions -n -E 'chomp; say if grep {-l} reductions {"$a/$b"} split "/"'
```

Not oneliner (though you can put write all of it in a single *very* long line if you want):

```bash
is_behind_symlink() {
    local path=$1
    while [ "$path" ]; do
        if [ -L "$path" ]; then
            return 0
        fi
        case $path in
            */*) path=${path%/*} ;;
            *) break ;;
        esac
    done
    return 1
}
```

```bash
while read -r path; do
    if is_behind_symlink "$path"; then
        echo "$path"
    fi
done < files.txt
```

You could also do this, but it spawns two subprocesses per file, so it's not fast:

```bash
is_behind_symlink() {
    local path=$1
    [[ "$(realpath -s "$path")" != "$(realpath -m "$path")" ]]
}
```

This is one process per path (which is still not great) and relies on parsing `namei -l` (doing so is not good style):

```bash
is_behind_symlink() {
    local path=$1
    namei -l -n "$path" | grep -q ^l
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This command which will recursively list symlinks whose target is
a directory, starting in the current directory:

```
find . -type l -xtype d
```

You may build your solution using an adaptation of this
[find command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).